# A way to insert a predefined text into Magit's commit message window?

Tags: magit

We have a convention that every commit message begins with an issue number.

I'd like to be able to programmatically insert the issue number part (computed by a separate function) into the commit window of Magit, when it first opens (that is, on pressing <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>).

How do I best do it? Where to look?

UPDATE: Here's what I'm currently using.

```lisp
(defun my-extract-branch-tag (branch-name)
  (let ((TICKET-PATTERN "\\(?:[[:alpha:]]+-\\)?\\([[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+\\)-.*"))
    (when (string-match-p TICKET-PATTERN branch-name)
       (s-upcase (replace-regexp-in-string TICKET-PATTERN "[\\1] " branch-name)))))

(defun my-git-commit-insert-branch ()
  (insert (my-extract-branch-tag (magit-get-current-branch))))

(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'my-git-commit-insert-branch)
```

For a branch name like `<username>-foo-123-<explanatory part>` it produces `[FOO-123]` in the first line of the commit message, to allow easy ticket auto-linking in Jira.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/44547/454

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a `git-commit-setup-hook` that can be used to prepare the commit message buffer.  Here comes a short example:

```
(defun my-git-commit-setup ()
  (insert "#123 "))

(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'my-git-commit-setup)
```

Answer (score 6):

**So** glad to find this older, but very helpful answer by @wasamasa:

On a gitflow-based branching model, (feature-)branches created by Bitbucket based on Jira issues (which are always in the form UPPERCASEALPHA-DIGITS), i use this to automatically insert the current issue number:

```
(let ((ISSUEKEY "[[:upper:]]+-[[:digit:]]+"))
 (when (string-match-p ISSUEKEY (magit-get-current-branch))
  (insert
   (replace-regexp-in-string
    (concat ".*?\\(" ISSUEKEY "\\).*")
    "- \\1: "
    (magit-get-current-branch)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep things really simple you could just invoke `magit-commit` with equivalent git arguments to accomplish the same thing:

```
(magit-commit `("--edit" ,(format "--message=%d: " 1234)))
```

Adding that command as an action to the popup with something like the following might help streamline your git workflow:

```
(defun my/read-issue-id ()
  "Return an issue ID default to the issue ID you are currently working on."
  ;; Or maybe completing-read w/unwrapping logic to extract the ID from a supplied list of issues...
  (read-number
   "Issue ID: "
   ;; Check your org-clock or make some REST request or something and use that as a default:
   42))

(defun my/issue-commit (issue-id)
  "Make a commit with a message starting with ISSUE-ID."
  (interactive (list (my/read-issue-id)))
  (magit-commit (append `("-e" ,(format "--message=%d: " issue-id))
                        (magit-commit-arguments))))

(magit-define-popup-action 'magit-commit-popup ?I "'Issue' commit" #'my/issue-commit)
```